# Closed span of sequence is underlying space.

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Consider the sequence $\{x^n\}_{n \geq 0}$ in $L^2[0,1]$. We can argue that this sequence satisfies $\overline{\text{span}}\{x^n\} = L^2[0,1]$ by showing that if $$\int_0^1 f(x)x^n dx=0,$$ for all $n \geq 0$, then $f=0$ almost everywhere. Although this works out relatively easily in this case, is there a way I can argue the same for $\{x^n\}_{n \geq K}$ for $K \in \mathbb{N}$? I think the argument would be in the same spirit, but I get stuck since we no longer have $\int_0^1 f(x)p(x)dx=0$ for any polynomial $p$. I was thinking maybe we could do this by induction using the work for before as a base case.

Suppose that the $\overline{\text{span}}\{x^n\}_{n \geq K} = L^2[0,1]$ for some $K \in \mathbb{N}$. Consider now, the sequence $\{x^n\}_{n \geq K+1}$, then if $f \in L^2[0,1]$ such that $f \perp x^n$ for $n \geq K+1$. Then we have $$\int_0^1 f^2(x) = \int_0^1 f(x)(f(x)-p_{K+1}(x)+p_{K+1}(x)) dx = \int_0^1 f(x)(f(x)-p_{K+1}(x))dx,$$ where $p_{K+1}$ is a polynomial of degree $\geq K+1$. This is where I get stuck and am unable to proceed. Of course I need to use the induction hypothesis, but am not sure how. Thank you for any feedback.

Krull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f(x)x^{K}$. Then $g \in L^{2}[0,1]$ and $\int_0^{1} x^{n} g(x)dx=0$ for all $n \geq 0$. Henec $g=0$ a.e which implies $f=0$ a.e..

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I follow the argument, with the exception of perhaps the simplest claim, which is $g \in L^2[0,1]$. Could you explain why this is so please?

Comment: @WolfgangKrull On $[0,1]$ $x^{K}$ is bounded by $1$ so $\int |x^{K}f(x)|^{2}dx \leq \int |f(x)|^{2}dx$.

Comment: Of course, I apologize. Thank you!

Comment: Does this still hold when we only consider even powers of $x$? That is $\{x^{2n}\}_{n \geq 0}$.